# QGIS - Drape (set Z value from raster) not working

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, drape

I have a shapefile layer containing lines and a raster layer imported from a Geosoft GXF.  I want to assign Z values to the nodes in the lines based on the intersected cells in the raster.  So I used the Processing Toolbox function Drape (set Z value from raster).  It doesn't work.  The Z values of the nodes don't change after running this function.  Is this thing broken?  Or is there something I need to know about the required inputs?  I'm displaying the vector and raster layers - the vectors are completely within the bounds of the raster.  They have the same CRS.

Comment: Update:  once the raster is saved as a Geotiff, Drape works.  Wouldn't have thought that the provenance of the raster would matter once imported, but here we are.